# Get column Lists from non-generic IEnumerable using Reflection

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

I have a method which takes a generic IEnumerable and generates lists of unique values for each column.  Needless to say this is very slow, I'm guessing it's due to all the reflection used.
Here's some sample code:

```
private void PopulateReferenceMatrices(IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        Type t = newValue.GetType();
        Type baseType = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        PropertyInfo[] properties;
        Dictionary<string, int> indexValues = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        properties = baseType.GetProperties();
        int numProperties = properties.Count(); 
        ListValues = new List<object>[numProperties];
        for (int i = 0; i < numProperties; i++)
        {
            indexValues.Add(properties[i].Name, i);
            FilterValues[i] = new List<object>();
        }
        //populate values into array
        foreach (dynamic da in newValue)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo d in properties)
            {
                Object property = d.GetValue(da);
                ListValues[indexValues[d.Name]].Add(property);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can I generate a list of values for each property without going through the IEnumerable row by row and casting each property as an object?

Is there a faster way to do something like this for each item in IEnumerable?:

```
public IList getRowValue(IEnumerable value, string propertyName)
{
    value.Select(x => x.propertyName).ToList();

}
```

Comment: What are you using reflection for, What are you trying to accomplish in general?

Comment: This is for a custom datagrid control with a listbox in each headerColumn to filter the data in the grid.  The ListValues are the values to check or uncheck in those listboxes.
Since I don't have the option of knowing the type being passed into the custom datagrid at runtime, I have to figure it out on the fly.

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic da`? What is `GetProperty`? Why are you looping over `PropertyInfo` objects only to pass just the `d.Name` to the method?

Comment: I thought dynamic might speed things up (and the docs said it treats most things like an Object anyway).  I thought there might have been a way to grab a property off a dynamic reference more easily.  GetProperty was a call to the CompilerServices.Versioned.CallByName function because someone had written that it was faster.  It wasn't (I'll change it back to GetValue(da).  As for properties, the first time is mainly to create a dictionary for quick access to an index, the other time I use it multiple times.

Comment: What is `a` for? It seems an awfully complicated way to get a sequential list of integers, as does doing a dictionary lookup to get an integer. What about `for (int j1 = 0; j1 < numProperties; ++j1) ListValues[j1].Add(properties[j1].GetValue(da));` (also `int numProperties = properties.Length;`). Also, why isn't this a generic method with `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: This is being called by an onItemsSourceChanged method on a datagrid, which gives me a non-generic IEnumerable.  As for why not have an IEnumerable<T>, I don't know, can you do that when you derive your class from an existing WPF object (that would make this tons easier)?  If so, how would I specify **T** in the XAML?  The code you suggest populates the values a little faster.  Thanks!  The dictionary lookup is mainly for elsewhere in the code where I need to retrieve the list based on the property name bubbled up from an event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had nothing to do with the IEnumerable or reflection.
Data hadn't been populated in the IEnumerable, so it was making thousands of database calls I was populating the matrix.
After fixing that issue, it loads in no time.

Answer (score 2):

One possible problem here is you are passing a non-generic collection which could be differents objects, so, create the propertyInfo should be inside the loop to make sure you can read that property from the object. If you are sure that all the objects inside the non-generic collection are the same type, you could read the propertyInfo outside the loop from the first object on the list (if it has at least one instance).

You could try this, see the comments on the code:

```
public static IList GetRowValue(IEnumerable value, string propertyName)
{
    // create an arraylist to be the result
    var result = new ArrayList();

    // loop in the objects
    foreach (var item in value)
    {
        // search for a property on the type of the object
        var property = item.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

        // if the property was found
        if (property != null)
        {
            // read the property value from the item
            var propertyValue = property.GetValue(item, null);

            // add on the result
            result.Add(propertyValue);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

See the working sample with differnt objects on the collections: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bPgk4h

Comment: Given how `baseType` is defined, it is a generic `IEnumerable<>` passed in as `IEnumerable` for some reason.